# Quill editor not displaying as expected in Angular 8 app

Tags: angular, angular8, quill

I am trying to add the Quill text editor to my Angular 8 project, but it is not rendering correctly on the browser.

There are no errors appearing in the console, and this is what is displayed in the browser:

[image: screen]

I followed the installation steps as outlined [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-quill).

Also, the following is mentioned in my angular.json:

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.css",
    "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
    "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css"
    ],
"scripts": ["./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js"]
```

Here are the imports in my NgModule:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    QuillModule.forRoot()
],
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div id="quill">
    <p>Content *</p>
    <quill-editor [styles]="editorStyle" placeholder="Enter Text" [modules]="config" formControlName="yourCtrlname"
required>
    </quill-editor>
</div>
```

Can someone please tell me why the editor isn't rendering correctly>

Comment: Have you checked the network requests if some js/css is not found (404)? That could be a hint that some path is wrong or some reference missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using quill in my angular project and I'm not sure why you have those hard-coded paths in your angular json - also there is a package that wraps quill in an angular module, I think that's what you're expecting to be defined by QuillModule, but I think you're just referencing the quill-source, not specific to angular.  I think if you remove those imports from angular.json and just run :

```
npm install --save quill
npm install --save ngx-quill
```

And then make sure you in your module your quillModule is importing from the ngx-quill

```
import { QuillModule } from 'ngx-quill';
```

I don't recall encountering any difficulties getting it up and running, but it looks like you have the quill library, but not the angular module - which seems to be the syntax you're using/expecting, so think you just need to install dependencies properly.

Answer (score 5):

Add inside index.html, it should now display it

```
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.bubble.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the [source](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill#for-standard-webpack-angular-cli-and-tsc-builds): "do not forget to include quill + theme css in your buildprocess, module or index.html!".

However, I was seeing the same behavior when I included style "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css" in angular.json. Changing it to style.css resolves the issue.
Add the following at the start of your style.css:

```
@import '~quill/dist/quill.core.css';
@import '~quill/dist/quill.bubble.css';
@import '~quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

better late than never

u need to add "@import '~quill/dist/quill.snow.css';" to your styles.less
worked for me after i did this.

Hope this still helps some1

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the imports

```
@import '~ quill / dist / quill.core.css';
@import '~ quill / dist / quill.snow.css';
```

in /webapp/content/scss/global.scss

and not directly in the scss file of your module

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have included the following in `styles.css`

```
@import '~quill/dist/quill.core.css';
@import '~quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
```

and also make sure they are applying while serving if not, import `styles.css` into `index.html`.